# Angular - DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': () => { } could not be cloned

Tags: angular, router, history

I'm stuck with an unexpected issue that wasn't exist yesterday !

Here is the code :

```
public submit(): void {
    const loaderId: string = this.loaderService.addLoader({ state: true, message: "Recherche en cours...", isMessageDisplayed: true });

    this.entityService.searchPublicEntities(this.searchValue?.value, this.categories?.value, this.city?.value).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.loaderService.deleteLoaderById(loaderId);

        this.router.navigate(["/resultat"], {
          state: { result: response.data, categories: this.categories },
          queryParams: {
            type: this.searchType,
            valeur: this.searchValue?.value,
            ville: this.city?.value,
            categories: this.categories?.value === "" ? "" : this.categories?.value.join(".") },
        });
      },
      (errorResponse) => {
        this.toastService.addToast({ button: "OK", duration: 0, type: "error", message: errorResponse.error.message });
        this.loaderService.deleteLoaderById(loaderId);
      }
    );
  }
```

When this code is executed. There is an error with the router.navigate !

Here is the error

```
Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': () => { } could not be cloned.
at BrowserPlatformLocation.pushState (common.js:166:1)
at PathLocationStrategy.pushState (common.js:417:1)
at Location.go (common.js:669:1)
at Router.setBrowserUrl (router.js:4702:1)
at TapSubscriber._tapNext (router.js:4186:1)
at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:40:1)
at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:66:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:1)
at zone.js:1279:1
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28661:1)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:1)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:1)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1600:1)
```

I don't understand why there is an error now because I'm using this method since 2 days et it worked perfectly.

I tried to find another topic on it but didn't find any...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just understand that window.history.pushState string size limit of 640k characters...

I'm going to use something else to pass the data

Comment: This is not a valid answer.You should check [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I can't validate my answer but I have to wait 2 days...

Comment: you gave me an idea, why my navigate doesnt work. It really has to do with the memory! thx.